# How to set a background image in an Grid element imported from @aws-amplify/ui-react

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I see the grid element has a property "backgroundImage", but haven't managed to get it to work.  Here is what I have tried (typescript):

```js
    return (
    <>
      <Grid
        templateColumns="500px 500px"
        templateRows="500px 500px"
        backgroundImage="./background.png"
      >
        <Card columnStart="1" columnEnd="-1">
          "Hello, world!"
        </Card>
        <View backgroundColor={"blue"}></View>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
```

Is there something wrong with my approach?

I am using `"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.6.0"`.

Comment: Where did you found backgroundImage property for Grid container?
so far, I couldn't find it in the documentation https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/components/grid?tab=props

Comment: In the Props Tab, at the bottom, you can see Style Props, here all common styles are listed. This is the link: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/theming/style-props. @DarrylRN

Comment: You forgot to wrap the url inside *url()*. Read more: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backgroundImage should be written inside `url`, `backgroundImage="url(/background.png)`"

You can try this:

```
return (
  <>
    <Grid
      templateColumns="500px 500px"
      templateRows="500px 500px"
      backgroundImage="url(./background.png)"
    >
      <Card columnStart="1" columnEnd="-1">
        "Hello, world!"
      </Card>
      <View backgroundColor={"blue"}></View>
    </Grid>
  </>
);
```

Comment: This worked after changing the path of background from "./background.png" to "/background.png".  I will attempt to edit your answer and accept.  Thank you!